# Does Entity Framework run database query again for already run query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I am developing an Asp.Net mvc project using Entity Framework code first approach. But I am trying to improve performance of my application. I am not clear that Entity Framework run database query again or not if I access the same condition again.

Here is my code:

```
var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault();// Database query will be run for this
var start = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault().Start; // Another query will be run for this
var end = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault().End; //Will another query be run again? Same query is run again for this
var price = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault().Price; //Here also
```

As you can see in the code, new query will be run to retrieve promotion start date. But when I retrieve end date, database will run the query again even if they are same query. I am confused by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer is correct there is another option to consider

Your original query

```
var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault();// Database query will be run for this
var start = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault().Start; // Another query will be run for this
var end = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault().End; //Will another query be run again? Same query is run again for this
var price = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault().Price; //Here also
```

Loading item as object stops reading data from the object

```
var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault();// Database query will be run for
```

Now all objects loaded are held in memory to read from without producing a query

```
item.Description 
item.Items //etc
```

Now to get data when you are lazy loading is
    var promotion = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault() 
And this will produce another query

```
promotion.Start
promotion.End
```

The question is if you read promotion everytime, it would be better to include it with the query (using eager loading) so when the the object is being fetched, it loads the child object

```
var item = context.Items.Include(x=>x.Promotions).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then it will be only one query to db to get data about the item and the promotion.

Specific selection

You can also update the query to select only the items you are interested in by using :

```
var customObj = context.Promotions.Where(p=>p.ItemId==itemId).Select(x=>new{x.Start, x.End, x.Price}).FirstOrDefault();
```

And this way you will receive the specific select and it will generate specific query for you.

*Note* 
**use sql profiler / ants profiler etc to see what sql you generate.**

Comment: So I retrieve like this context.Items.Include(x=>x.Promotions). Then I get an item like this var item = items.FirstOrDefault(). If U access item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault(), query will be run again?

Comment: no it will include by default all instances associated against the item

Comment: What if one to one relationship? Example var item = context.items.FirstOrDefault(); var start = item.Promotion.Start; var end = item.Promotion.End . As you can see, I did not cached them assign to a variable. So another query run again when I retrieve promotion end date?

Comment: In that case you should select only the specific fields instead of the whole object

Comment: So you mean new query will be run each time I access a property of promotion?

Comment: As long it does not get disposed yes

Comment: Opp. I ve got to fix my whole project. Thanks a lot for answering me. But it get disposed mostly after view is returned. Is it?

Comment: If you do not do any specific disposing of the object it will be released by garbage collector automatically

Answer (score 1):

The data in the database could have changed in the meantime, that's why EF is running the query again.

To improve the performance, simply cache the result yourself:

```
var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(); // Database query will be run for this
var promotion = item.Promotions.FirstOrDefault(); // Another query will be run for this
var start = promotion.Start; // No additional query
var end = promotion.End;     // No additional query
var price = promotion.Price; // No additional query
```

BTW: This has nothing to do with Lazy Loading. Lazy Loading is related to lazily loading other entities that it references. It is not related to its data.

Comment: What if one to one relationship? Example var item = context.items.FirstOrDefault(); var start = item.Promotion.Start; var end = item.Promotion.End . As you can see, I did not cached them assign to a variable. So another query run again when I retrieve promotion end date?